# Disable validation in QSpinBox

Tags: qt, validation, qspinbox

Hence I have a QSpinBox, and want to unset validation for writing not only int values, but also string in it. 
Please help me to fix this.
I have tried this, but it does not work:

```
class Spinbox:public QSpinBox
{
public:

    Spinbox(QWidget* parent=0)
        :QSpinBox(parent){}
    void setLineEdit(QLineEdit *l)
    {
        QSpinBox::setLineEdit(l);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Spinbox de;
    QLineEdit le;
    le.setValidator(0);
    le.setText("text");
    de.setLineEdit(&le);
    de.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt docs say that:

> If QLineEdit::validator() for the lineEdit returns 0, the internal
>   validator of the spinbox will be set on the line edit.

Thus, in order to disable the QSpinBox's built in validator, you need to set your own (dummy?). I.e.

```
class Validator : public QValidator
{
public:
    State validate(QString &input, int &pos ) const
    {
        return QValidator::Acceptable;
    }
};

[..]

Spinbox de;
QLineEdit le;
le.setValidator(new Validator());
le.setText("text");
de.setLineEdit(&le);
de.show();
```

Comment: @EduardRostomyan use your own validator instead of QIntValidator.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan, I have updated my answer and added a dummy validator that allows to set anything in the line edit.